# Sum adjacent cells down the column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want to add, say `A3 + B3` and have the sum of those two cells in `C3`, but apply this principle to the whole columns, so I will also get sum of `A4 + B4` in `C4` etc. all the way down to the sum of `A432 + B432` in `C432`.

I am sure it's quite simple if you know how.

Answer (score 2):

In cell C3 type the formula

```
=A3+B3
```

select C3. Right click » Copy. Select `C432`. To select the entire range C3–C432, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>. Paste via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

There are a dozen ways to do the same. As this is the most basic of tasks, perhaps a tutorial would be useful.

Comment: Works a treat!Thanks for your help. I guess a tutorial is the way to go for this user......